# Query for remove object inside array using gte condition MonggoDB

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

Hello I'm new to monggodb query, I'm trying to delete object inside my array using mongo3t query which is the date going forward from 2021-09-13.

My current data is: attendance

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6070b991d6231f8c205cb093"
    },
    "UserId": "5",
    "Ranges": [
        {
            "DateFrom": {
                "DateTime": {
                    "$date": "2021-09-12T00:00:00.000Z"
                },
                "Ticks": {
                    "$numberLong": "637536960000000000"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "DateFrom": {
                "DateTime": {
                    "$date": "2021-09-13T00:00:00.000Z"
                },
                "Ticks": {
                    "$numberLong": "637536960000000000"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "DateFrom": {
                "DateTime": {
                    "$date": "2021-09-15T00:00:00.000Z"
                },
                "Ticks": {
                    "$numberLong": "637536960000000000"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the query I tried to execute,

```
db.getCollection('attendance').update(
    { UserId: "5" },
    { $pull: { 'Ranges': { DateFrom: { DateTime: { $gte: new Date(2021, 09, 13) } } } } }
);
```

My query runs successfully with message "Updated 1 existing record(s) in 4ms", but upon checking the data nothing happens.

Comment: can you write the data in JSON format? you can use [this](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print) Datefrom looks like an array , but it has fields.

Comment: @Takis_ I have updated the sample data now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems ok, removed only the last element.

Query

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z1Rhj04iRcX)

```js
db.collection.update({
  UserId: "5"
},
{
  $pull: {
    Ranges: {
      "DateFrom.DateTime": {
        $gte: ISODate("2021-09-14T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: May I also know how can I add another UserId to the filter?

Comment: probably you mean this [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v0i-fk7E7D-) but use multi-document update, not updateOne method, depends on your needs

Answer (score 0):

you could use update pipeline

```
db.con
    .collection("attendance")
    .updateOne({ UserId:"5" }, 
   [
    {$project:{
      UserId:1,
      Ranges:{
        $filter:{
          input:"$Ranges",
          as:"z",
          cond:
            {
              $gte:["$$z.DateFrom.DateTime", new Date(2021, 09, 13)]
            }
          
        }
      }
    }}
   ]
   )
```